# Only include / enable form fields if checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form, with a big search field at the top.

There is a also a **bells and whistles** checkbox - when that is ticked 3 additional fields are displayed.

I want the form method to be set to GET instead of POST.

When the form is submitted the URL ends up as:

`test.php?q=tree&whistles=y&exa=any&fmt=cat&opt=img`

I'd like to change is that if the bells and whistles check box is not ticked, the 3 other fields (4 including the "whistles" checkbox" are not submitted in the form, so that the url appears as this instead:

`test.php?q=tree`

Then if a user ticks the checkbox, and thereby wants to search for additional things, those fields will be included in the search.

This is my starting code:

```js
// show / hide bells and whistles checkbox 

$(function() {

  $('#whistles').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $('#options').show();
    } else {
      $('#options').hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form action='test.php' method='get'>
  <input type='text' class='form-control form-control-lg' id='q' name='q' placeholder='Search'>
  <div style='margin-top:5px;'><input type='checkbox' id='whistles' name='whistles' value='y' />&nbsp;<label for='whistles'>Show Bells and Whistles</label></div>
  <p></p>
  <div id='options' style='display:none' class="alert alert-secondary">
    <div class='form-row'>
      <div class='form group col-md-4'>
        <label for='exa'>Match Type</label>
        <select name='exa' id='exa' class='form-control form-control-sm'>
          <option value='' disabled='disabled'>Match</option>
          <option value='any'>Any</option>
          <option value='exact'>Exact</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class='form group col-md-4'>
        <label for='fmt'>Format</label>
        <select name='fmt' id='fmt' class='form-control form-control-sm'>
          <option value='' disabled='disabled'>Format</option>
          <option selected='selected' value='cat'>Category</option>
          <option value='subcat'>Subcategory</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class='form group col-md-4'>
        <label for='opt'>Output</label>
        <select name='opt' id='opt' class='form-control form-control-sm'>
          <option value='' disabled='disabled'>Output</option>
          <option selected='selected' value='img'>Image</option>
          <option value='emj'>Font</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success' style='margin:5px 0px 15px 0px;'>Go!</button>
</form>
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Would I have to use jQuery detach() maybe? If so, unfortunately I am clueless about how I would do that.

---

Fixed by doing the following:

I added this JS to check if the checkbox is checked when the page is submitted. If it is, enable the additional form fields. If not, disable them:

```
var foo1 = document.getElementById("whistles").checked;

if (foo1 == true) { document.getElementById("exa").disabled = false; } else { document.getElementById("exa").disabled = true; }
if (foo1 == true) { document.getElementById("fmt").disabled = false; } else { document.getElementById("fmt").disabled = true; }
if (foo1 == true) { document.getElementById("opt").disabled = false; } else { document.getElementById("opt").disabled = true; }
```

Then us the JS from the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50778666/4532066) to toggle the enable / disable attributes when the checkbox is checked / unchecked.

Comment: There more than one way to do that, one way is to make the elements `disabled` when hiding and remove `disabled` attribute when showing because disabled inputs/elements won't be submitted. Also, you can submit the form using `jQuery` by filtering the visible elements by making the hidden inputs `disabled` before submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// show/hide bells and whistles checkbox 

$(function () {
    $('#whistles').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#exa').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#fmt').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#opt').removeAttr('disabled');

            $('#options').show();
        } else {
            $('#exa').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#fmt').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#opt').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            $('#options').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t2a4fwbn/

Comment: Thanks for your help @erlangparasu - unfortunately, if I submit the form, with only text in the search field, and the checkbox not selected, the URL returned contains all of the form fields, rather than just the `q` field.

Comment: I just test my code again and its work.. the browser open just q field if checkbox is unchecked. also please see @the-alpha 's answer for description

Comment: Thanks again @erlangparasu - I see on the jsfiddle it works okay, because you end up with a url of `https://fiddle.jshell.net/t2a4fwbn/show/test.php?q=tree` if the checkbox is not submitted, and `https://fiddle.jshell.net/t2a4fwbn/show/test.php?q=tree&whistles=y&exa=any&fmt=cat&opt=img` if it is. I'm testing on a windows PC, and have tested on IIS and also XAMPP and all of the form fields are submitted when testing there, on both Firefox and Chrome. I wonder why the difference?

Comment: I worked out that in the jsfiddle, that the select elements have had `disabled='disabled'` added to them in the html, which is why the code works. Thanks

Comment: Updated my question to include the workaround I used to get this to work. I had to add some JS to handle checking if the checkbox was checked when the page is submitted. Thanks again for your help.